# How to ignore Json root name in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a question regarding Json serialization / deserialization in Spring Boot.

I have an entity class, what has embedded id:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_TABLE")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

   private UserPK id;
   private String name;

}

/* Getters and Setters excluded */
public class UserPK implements Serializable {
    private Long userId;
    private Long personalId;
}
```

Now if I serialize an object, Spring Boot put a root "id" tag inside JSON. Is it possible to exclude this, and put it into the same level of the name property?

Actual result:

```
{
    "id":{"userId":321, "personalId":222},
    "name":"John Doe"
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "userId":321,
    "personalId":222,
    "name":"John Doe"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question of "how to ignore" is a bit misleading, since you just want to put a string as a key, instead of an object. Usually what you're looking for is done by using Data Transfer Objects that carry data between layers using special representations that usually are structurally different (just like you want). Create a special DTO, say `UserDto`, define its structure, convert `User` to `UserDto` in your controller (manually, using `MapStruct`, whatever) and put the DTO in the response entity.

Comment: What you are looking for if you are using Jackson to serialize/deserialize is the \@JsonUnwrapped annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may annotate `User.id` field with `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to effectively flatten the underlying structure like this:

```java
public class User {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private UserPK id;
    private String name;
}
```

See the [docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html).

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted, exactly.